# Are there any possible values for the 6th parameter to OpenCV's CvMat* cvInitMatHeader

Tags: c, opencv

I'm referring to the C
    CvMat* cvInitMatHeader(CvMat* mat, int rows, int cols, int type,   can int step be 
    void* data=NULL, int step=CV_AUTOSTEP)
anything other than CV_AUTOSTEP  are there any other enums the 6th param could be like cvCreateImage has:

```
    #define IPL_DEPTH_SIGN 0x80000000

#define IPL_DEPTH_1U     1
#define IPL_DEPTH_8U     8
#define IPL_DEPTH_16U   16
#define IPL_DEPTH_32F   32

#define IPL_DEPTH_8S  (IPL_DEPTH_SIGN| 8)
#define IPL_DEPTH_16S (IPL_DEPTH_SIGN|16)
#define IPL_DEPTH_32S (IPL_DEPTH_SIGN|32)
```

If so in what file are they #defined....

Answer (score 1):

You should always check the [OpenCV's official documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html?highlight=cvinitmatheader#CvMat%2a%20cvInitMatHeader%28CvMat%2a%20mat,%20int%20rows,%20int%20cols,%20int%20type,%20void%2a%20data,%20int%20step%29) first.

```
CvMat* cvInitMatHeader(CvMat* mat,
                       int rows,
                       int cols,
                       int type,
                       void* data=NULL,
                       int step=CV_AUTOSTEP)
```

You would find out, that ***step*** is *"full row width in bytes of the assigned data. By default, the minimal possible step is used which assumes there are no gaps between subsequent rows of the matrix."*

Comment: I meant are there any other enums that can stand in for the 6th param...lik cvCreateMat  has CV_8UC1, CV8UC2...ETC....couldn't find in documentation

Comment: @user2735131: If there would be some specific list of constant that you could use, the documentation would state so. It seems like you either use `CV_AUTOSTEP` and minimal possible step will be used, or you will specify the width explicitly.